# Optimizing and finding the computation of this inequality

Tags: java, c, algorithm

Let's assume I have a set of integers, out of which I want to find out all the maximum number of integers which satisfy a particular inequality. For sake of explanation,

r<sub>1</sub>, r<sub>2</sub>, r<sub>3</sub>, ... r<sub>n</sub> when r<sub>i</sub> is a positive integer. I want the to find the maximum z which would range from 1 to n for which r<sub>i</sub> <= 0.5 * (r<sub>1</sub> + r<sub>2</sub> + r<sub>3</sub> + ... + r<sub>n</sub>) for **all** i from 3 to z. How to approach such problems? I have approaches the naive method of finding all subsets of sizes from 1 to n and iterating through each of the subset to check whether each element satisfies the condition or not? Any other approach?

Comment: Can the values be negative?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Unless I have made a miscalculation, if `rn > 0` for all `n`, then any `z >= 2` would fulfil the condition, so the maximum `z` would be `n`

Comment: No @ThoAppelsin , In case of {1,2,3} not applicable for any such subset of size greater than three the equality doesn't hold.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin: Consider r = { 8, 1, 1 }.  z=n is not the case here (r1 > 0.5*(8+1+1)).

Comment: Well, what would be the answer you'd like to have with a set like `{ 8, 1, 1 }` where no `z` fulfils the condition? Is there a condition like `r_n` being an increasing set?

Comment: Is O (n) or O (n log n) fast enough?

Comment: @ThoAppelsin in that case z=2 is a solution

Comment: Is the sequence of r1, r2, r3, ...rz is fixed, or I can change the sequence?

Comment: I'm sorry for all the bad I've caused for this question... I'll try my best to give a proper and good answer to it within today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel kind of bad, especially for the false edit I have done to the question... Anyway:

First, the most naive, direct and straightforward way to solve this question; which would be to start off from the 1st number in the set, calculate the `n`th partial sum on each step, compare that partial sum with the double of each element starting from the 3rd element, up till the `n`th element. If the comparison holds for each element, mark the current last as the maximum `z`.

The following macro `largestzfinder`, dependant on the function `largestzfinderfunc` does that:

```
// indices are zero based

#define largestzfinder(_x_) largestzfinderfunc((_x_), sizeof(_x_) / sizeof(*_x_))

unsigned int largestzfinderfunc( unsigned int set[], size_t size ) {

    unsigned int largestz = 0;
    unsigned int partialsumsofar = 0;
    int disqualified;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ){
        partialsumsofar += set[i];

        disqualified = 0;
        for ( int j = 2; j <= i; j++ ) {    // for all j from 2 to i (inclusive)
            if ( 2 * set[j] > partialsumsofar ) {
                disqualified = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( !disqualified )    // if comparison held for all j
            largestz = i;
    }

    return largestz;
}
```

With this method, we gradually reach to our `largestz` by starting off from the *smallest z* and finding the next *bigger z* until we reach the *largest*. We could simplify that process by starting from the end, in which case we wouldn't have to go through all that other `z`s except for the *largest* one, and we don't need the others either...

To do that, we would need to pre-calculate the whole sum, and then reduce the elements from the last one by one, make comparisons with shrinking partial sums the same way, and return an answer as soon as we find a non `disqualified` candidate. Following code does that:

```
// indices are zero based

#define largestzfinder(_x_) largestzfinderfunc((_x_), sizeof(_x_) / sizeof(*_x_))

unsigned int largestzfinderfunc( unsigned int set[], size_t size ) {

    unsigned int largestz = 0;
    unsigned int partialsumsofar = 0;
    int disqualified;

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        partialsumsofar += set[i];

    for ( int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){

        disqualified = 0;
        for ( int j = 2; j <= i; j++ ) {    // for all j from 2 to i (inclusive)
            if ( 2 * set[j] > partialsumsofar ) {
                disqualified = 1;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ( !disqualified ) {  // if comparison held for all j
            largestz = i;
            break;
        }

        partialsumsofar -= set[i];  // updates/reduces partialsumsofar
    }

    return largestz;
}
```

Now, you see, we check if the condition holds for every single element from 3rd to last, one by one... while we could just check it for the largest among them! If `largestamongthem <= partialsumsofar / 2`, then all of them will simply be less than or equal to the partial sum that far.

How would you determine the `largestsofar`? Well, things get complicated, especially when you do the process starting from the end. If we were doing it from the start, then we could just start off with `largestsofar = 0;` and compare each subsequent element with it, update our `largestsofar`.

One way to do it, is to make a new array of integers that has the same size with the set array, which will hold the `largestsofar` for each point. The following code uses that method:

```
// indices are zero based

#define largestzfinder(_x_) largestzfinderfunc((_x_), sizeof(_x_) / sizeof(*_x_))

unsigned int largestzfinderfunc( unsigned int set[], size_t size ) {

    unsigned int largestz = 0;
    unsigned int partialsumsofar = 0;
    unsigned int * largestsofar = calloc( size, sizeof * largestsofar );

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        partialsumsofar += set[i];

    largestsofar[0] = 0;
    largestsofar[1] = 0;
    largestsofar[2] = set[2];
    for ( int i = 3; i < size; i++ )
        largestsofar[i] = (set[i] > largestsofar[i-1]) ? set[i] : largestsofar[i-1];

    for ( int i = size - 1; i >= 0; i-- ){

        if ( 2 * largestsofar[i] <= partialsumsofar ) {
            largestz = i;
            break;
        }

        partialsumsofar -= set[i];
    }

    free( largestsofar );

    return largestz;
}
```

Well, if you aren't really happy with allocating memory, keeping a list of largest number so far in it, I'm with you. The following recursive function does the thing, without keeping a list. It also looks far shorter. The downside is that it is less reader-friendly. Here:

```
// indices are zero based

#define largestzfinder(_x_) largestzfinderfunc((_x_), sizeof(_x_) / sizeof(*_x_), (_x_)[0] + (_x_)[1], 1, 0)

unsigned int largestzfinderfunc( unsigned int set[], size_t size, unsigned int partialsumsofar, unsigned int i, unsigned int largestsofar ){
    unsigned int j;
    if ( i < size - 1 && ( j = largestzfinderfunc( set, size, partialsumsofar + set[i + 1], i + 1, ( set[i + 1] > largestsofar ) ? set[i + 1] : largestsofar ) ) ){
        return j;
    }
    else if ( 2 * largestsofar <= partialsumsofar ) {
        return i;
    }
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Let me explain what it does briefly: By a call to the macro, it first passes `r_0 + r_1` as `partialsumsofar`, `1` as the current z to be checked, and `0` as the largest number up till the `r_1` (this is because `r_0` and `r_1` are not to be considered during comparison).

It doesn't check right away, however; provided that this was not the last element (`i < size - 1`), it will call for the function one level beyond, with `partialsumsofar` updated, current z to be checked incremented, and largest number to be updated as well. This will be done until the last element is reached.

After that, the recursion tree will collapse. If the last one fails to satisfy the condition, it will return a `0`, causing the parent recursion branch to check if he/she satisfies the condition.

As soon as one parent satisfies the condition, it will return its current z, causing each parent to return the same z, since they all store the returned value under `j` and return it, if `j` is not zero.

In essence, it actually does allocate memory for each `largestsumsofar` and `partialsumsofar` and all, but it frees all those one by one as the recursion tree/line/whatever collapses.

This wasn't so *brief*, but whatever, I hope I've done it right this time. I want to get over this question now...